# Javascript function fails to execute in safari, firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, function

```
<script>
function moveon() {
//display a modal dialog to ask the user question
var answer = confirm("Ready to move on? ");

// If they clicked the "ok" button, make the browser load a new page. 
if (answer)
window.location = "http://google.com";
}

//run the function defined above 1 minute (60,000 milliseconds) from now
setTimeout(moveon, 60000); 
</script>
```

I'm wondering why this code fragment failed to execute in my  html file even though it is straight from javascript definitive guide.

i'm a mac user so haven't had a chance to test on pc.

Comment: What is not working? Are you not getting the pop-up or are not getting redirected to the url after clicking on okay? I ran the exact same script in chrome console (window 7 OS) and it worked

Comment: Should work just fine.  I plopped that exact code into my console (chrome on mac osx) and it prompted me and redirected me when I confirmed.  What is your exact issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
window.location.href = "http://google.com";
```

Comment: Just noticed that setTimeout(), thanks. The lack of braces around the if block had me confused.